# If condition inside qlikview varaible

Tags: variables, if-statement, qlikview

I want to show all employees who have greater than 10,000 amount i do this but this is not working

```
=if(RetBal < 10000,RetBal)
```

and then i save this in variable

Comment: `if(RetBal > 10000,RetBal)`

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are having one row per customer <-> RetBal you still need to use some aggregation function in your expression(s)

There are two ways to achieve this in your case:

- IF

`if( sum(RetBal) > 10000, sum(RetBal) )`

Usually `IF` is slower so personally im trying to avoid it as much as possible. It's not a big issue if you have relatively small datasets. But with big data sets the delay is visible.

- Set Analysis

`sum( {< empId = {"=sum(RetBal) > 10000"} >} RetBal )`

[Set Analysis](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/February2018/Subsystems/Hub/Content/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-analysis-expressions.htm) is considered faster because it doesn't scan the whole table

Can download example app from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QS7dD78GaN5K-yGMzh9zJ-A2laMyEn-H)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just mistaken the greater than sign " **>** "